# Flutter web app paused at web_entrypoint.dart

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am new to flutter, I was trying to build a web app , and i am trying to save text data to firestore but whenever i run my web app it doesn't run and a new file is opened named web_entrypoint.dart and it hightlights this code
[This is the highlighted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqT15.png)
i have already included firebase script to the html of web app

Here is the screenshot of vscode:
[vs code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN02G.png)

this is my main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to initialize');
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Versions -
firebase_core: ^1.3.0
cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
Dart: 2.13.4

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: No I didn't get any error on the console

Comment: Okay, looks like your code hit a breakpoint. Please share a screenshot that captures the entire VS Code screen

Comment: Now I have added the screenshot

Comment: Click on the `Play` icon in blue on the top right corner to get past the breakpoint.

Comment: it worked, thx for your time, I added google analytics script in the html file and it start working.

Comment: Alright, great. I updated the title and I'll add answer shortly incase any other person faces this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that your app paused at the breakpoint, you can just click on the `Play` button and the app should continue running as expected.

More reading: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging

Comment: Yep, that's right. You have to click play in top right corner of the screen